# Don't include a JS library in webpack build (with the assumption that it'll be included in a script tag)

Tags: javascript, typescript, webpack

I'm using a large library (around 1 MB) along with webpack for building. The library is just used normally - it's in package.json's `dependencies`, and at some point in my code I import it with an `import from <lib_name>` (this is in Typescript).

So right now, when I run a `webpack build`, the end result `bundle.js` contains all (or most? not sure how much webpack trims, actually) of the library's code. So even my barebones application that's only a couple lines of code and an import has that big 1MB build size.

What I would like to do is have the library not be thrown into the final build, and instead basically have in my HTML file something like this:

```
<script src="https://some.cdn.here/thelibrary-v0.0.0.min.js"></script>
<script src="bundle.js"></script>
```

In other words, the files in the build would be something like:

```
BEFORE:
  dist/
    bundle.js -- 1005 KB

AFTER:
  dist/
    thelibrary-v0.0.0.min.js -- 1000 KB
    bundle.js -- 5 KB
```

Where `bundle.js` becomes a very small file with just my code, and it simply expects the library to be loaded beforehand. To be clear - `bundle.js` would still be using things from the library and would need it to run. I'm not sure if this is actually possible or not, because I don't have a good understanding of how webpack actually handles imports and stuff (especially in conjunction with uglify/minification). Is it possible to do something like this, and if so, how?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It can be done with [externals](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/externals/).

```
module.exports = {
  //...
  externals: {
    jquery: 'jQuery'// thelibrary in your case
  }
};
```